# " TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined" and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The bot works completely fine before but suddenly it crashed itself with the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined" and even if it don't, I am not able to add roles using the bot.(TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null) Did discord changed anything? Please help me with this. Thank you.

Here is the errors I got: https://pastebin.com/PWc8MAvU

Below is the code I've been using

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION','GUILD_MEMBER', 'USER'] });

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error when fetch msg ', error);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(reaction.message.id === "the id of message for users to react to"){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
            console.log(user.username+' verified')            
            let member = bot.guilds.resolve('My server's id').members.resolve(user.id);
            member.roles.add('Id of the role I want to add');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that sometimes, the member isn't cached yet when you try to get their roles (By default, only a small part of members are cached). Instead of using [resolve()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=resolve), I would suggest using [fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) and an async system, so if the user isn't cached, the bot will cache it first before getting their roles.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION','GUILD_MEMBER', 'USER'] });

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error when fetch msg ', error);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(reaction.message.id === "the id of message for users to react to"){
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
            console.log(user.username+' verified');
            let guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("My server's id");
            guild.members.fetch(user.id)
            .then(member -> {
                member.roles.add('Id of the role I want to add');
            }).catch(console.error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Didn't thought of it before. It works so well now, It's weird that it works so well before and suddenly not working tho. But the problem is solved. Thanks again!

Comment: After running the bot for a while, it still crashed itself with the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined" for no reason, even after restarting it do it again after a while. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: The error happened in ./node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:11 btw